# Mysql Unix-Timestamp Date Format

Tags: mysql, datetime, unix-timestamp

In mysql database I store date column as unix-timestamp format (for example:`1264105904`). I want  to convert this date to datetime like `"Oct 11, 2011 6:25 am PDT"` in select statement. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
select date_format(from_unixtime(1264105904),'%b %d, %Y %l:%i %p PDT');
```

should do what you want